# jQuery UI Draggable: Get drag offset of A LOT of dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm creating a `<table>` element in the DOM and using javascript to dynamically append many cells to it. For the sake of explanation let's say I create 10 rows with 10 fields per row. I'm using simple counters to assign unique IDs for the div containers inside of those fields. Easy enough. This is what I get:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><div id="field0"><div id="handle0"></div></div></td></tr>
    .....
    <tr><td><div id="field99></div id="handle99"></div></div></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Note that the numbers 0-99 are what is dynamically appended to each element ID.
I now want to go ahead and attach the jQueryUI .draggable function to each handle and retrieve the coordinates of each handle relative to each surrounding parent div like so:

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
var dragHandle = $('#handle' + counter);
var dragField = $('#field' + counter);
    dragHandle.draggable({
                    containment: dragField,
                    scroll: false,
                    drag: function () { 
                             var offset = $(this).offset();
                             var xPos = (offset.left) - $(this).offsetParent().offset().left;
                             var yPos = (offset.top) - $(this).offsetParent().offset().top;
                                  console.log(xPos); 
                                  console.log(yPos); // These add up?!
                          }
    });
}
```

Now, the functions work, the table gets properly initialized and all of the individual handles in the table are now draggable.

**The problem** is that the `xPos` and `yPos` values that are returned by the above function are not the correct coordinates relative to each field but instead they add up.

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious and would really appreciate if someone could help.

**Edit:** The example above uses console.log for simplification. My original script performs more complex computations in the on drag event. I won't be able to use a class selector to go through all of the elements like someone suggested in the comments because I need to retrieve unique offset and position values for each unique handle ID relative to its unique containment ID.

Comment: I see a few issues here, `offset` is an object and you are trying to log it as  a string. Also rather than looping through all the fields to add the draggable, why don't you add a class so that you can easily reference everything that needs to be draggable?

Comment: Fixed the console.log error. I dont't think I can work with classes because I need access to the offset values of each unique handle ID relative to each unique containment ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var xPos=(offset.left)-$(this).position( ).left
var yPos=(offset.top)-$(this).position( ).top

Answer (score 2):

Instead of offsetParent you can modify.

var xPos = (offset.left) - $(this).parent().offset().left;
var yPos = (offset.top) - $(this).parent().offset().top;